# Test cases always failed other than Firefox

Tags: eclipse, selenium-webdriver, jasmine

```
I want to run Test cases on Multiple browser.
```

i write following code to test Title of Webpage. This test is passed with firefox but shows skipped or fail when i try to run in other browsers.

```
public class clsTestCase {
    WebDriver driver;
    String baseurl,nodeurl;
    @BeforeTest
    public void beforeTest() throws MalformedURLException
    {
      baseurl="http://www.google.com/";
      nodeurl="http://192.168.1.100:5566/wd/hub/";
        DesiredCapabilities cap=DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();
        cap.setBrowserName("internet explorer");
        cap.setPlatform(Platform.WINDOWS);
       driver=new RemoteWebDriver(new URL (nodeurl), cap);

    }


    @Test
    public void testAdd() {
        driver.get(baseurl);
        Assert.assertEquals("Google", driver.getTitle());
    }
 @AfterTest
  public void aftrTest()
 {
     driver.quit();

 }    
}
```

When i changed statement

```
DesiredCapabilities cap=DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();
cap.setBrowserName("internet explorer");
```

to

```
 DesiredCapabilities cap=DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
cap.setBrowserName("firefox");
```

Then test case is Passed.
Why its not passed in IE or Chrome for Same code?

Comment: I test in Python. You may need to download the "Chrome" and "IE" browser drivers for selenium first before you can test against them. please refer to those two links: https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver; https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver

Comment: alternatively to @Vadivelan's answer you can do setting of IEDriver from command line too when you are starting your client and server on grid.

Answer (score 0):

You should set the Chrome driver and IE driver before initialisation of the driver.

System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver","Path of your IEServer.exe");
WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();

System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.chrome","Path of your chromeserver.exe");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();